# why my overlay transparent background color is not covering whole screen

Tags: html, css, background-color, transparent

I have this call to action page, which has a background image and a background color on top of the image; however, I can't make the background-color to take whole screen. little help here! Thanks PS: I'm using bootstrap cdns also. 
link to page: http://pctechtips.org/apps/conf/
css:

```
/*
    full stack conf style
*/

body {
    background-image: url("http://travelhdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Chicago-Wallpaper-3.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -10;
}

.hero {
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(31, 34, 118, 0.5);
    z-index: -5;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- bootstrap cdns css,js,popper.js,jquery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<!-- bg-info = background blue, text-center = text white -->
<body class="text-white">
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1 class="display-1" style="margin-top:12rem">Full Stack Conf</h1>
            <p class="lead mb-5">Comming Soon, a One-day Conference About All Things Javascript!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Sign up</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One issue might be that you are using `top` and `bottom` on your `.hero` but have not set a `position` on it

Comment: ok I added position: absolute, and width:100% and it looks better; however, background-image is not covering the whole screen. how can I fix that http://pctechtips.org/apps/conf/

Comment: well since the `.hero` is now `absolute` and not taking up space in the DOM you will have to give your `body` dimensions. Maybe like a `min-height: 100vh;` and `min-width: 100vw;` should make the body at minimum take up the whole viewport

Comment: how to make background-img to take whole page?

Comment: Thanks all if anyone is interested when searching this topic here's the answer: http://pctechtips.org/apps/conf/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the folks who commented above here's the answer

```
/*
    full stack conf style
*/

body {
    background-image: url("http://travelhdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Chicago-Wallpaper-3.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -10;
}

.hero {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(31, 34, 118, 0.5);
    z-index: -5;
}
```